# How Do I Stop NSTableView Drag Images Shrinking When Leaving The Table?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I have an app with multiple NSOutlineViews, in one window, with drag and drop enabled and working. I can successfully drag items from one outline to another.

When dragging within a single outline, I automatically get a nice image of the rows I am dragging next to the mouse, the same size as the source. However, when the mouse leaves the bounds of the source outliner, the image shrinks right down so that any text is illegible.

I would like the dragged image to remain full size when the mouse is above ***a window of my app***.

I can't see anything that relates to this in NSDraggingInfo, which seems to be the only thing I have available to monitor the images in updateDraggingItemsForDrag.

I notice that if I drag multiple rows, the image of each row shrinks, but the layout of the rows stays the same, so it must be scaling at the level of each individual row image, not as one.

How do I control this please?